# Int data type storage always 4 bytes?

Tags: types, integer, storage, sqldatatypes

Quick question does using an INT in MySQL always result in 4 bytes of storage no matter the value, e.g. Does the value of 5 use the same amount of bytes as 2000000?

Or is the data type storage a maximum storage?

Comment: I think you can assume that it a MySQL `INT` value will always occupy (at least) 4 bytes on disc.  The extra performance cost and complexity of compressing `INT` fields are too large for compression to be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure the size does not depend on the value.

Comment: That's what I think, just trying to understand if I should use INT or BIGINT for a transaction id on a transactions table, the consensus is that it should be INT due to storage requirements but I can see that the max number will be exhausted in the future so just want to future proof it

Comment: So you are handling a lot of GB of data i suppose

Comment: If you now consider that you can store 2147483647 ids until int runs out, and bigint is twice as big as int (8byte) you waste 2147483647 * 4byte of space since you need it after int would run out which is about 8.5GB of space if I'm not mistaken, I guess that's worth it
But I dont know the circumstances and am personally not very experienced with this much data

Comment: With unsigned you get a max value of 4294967295 from an int, which is still huge, don't get me wrong I won't be dealing with that amount of data but when the table is cleared out I still need to have the transaction id as unique so incremental is my only thought? There will be a time maybe in years and years to come where I may exhaust the biggest number of BIGINT unsigned 18446744073709551615 highly unlikely but may be possible, by that time I will have changed the system anyway. But don't want to waste space either.

Comment: To be honest I wasn't aware that unsigned datatypes are a thing in SQL.
But ok, is there still a problem now? I don't really get if there's a problem anymore, you know that you probably will run out but you care about space so you kinda have to decide what's more important to you. I pesonally would go with the int but as I already mentioned, I don't know the circumstances so I can't tell what's right for you

Comment: It's just trying to get a balance really, ideally I would want to pick int due to saving storage space long term but will need a way to get around when it runs out. I could just change the int to BIGINT in the database when the time comes?

Comment: Well as far as I know you could just alter the column when the time comes. As long as there are no FK references or something on this ID everything should work fine

Comment: Maybe close this question? :)

Comment: I take it I just mark it as answered closes this as I don't have a close option?

Comment: I think thats the only option yes :)